# How can I copy the last pre-filled cell with autofill for as below?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm creating code where I need the column where the date is to use autofill. However, this column (AA) has to always be copied from the last cell filled in AA to the last one filled based on A. But I'm experiencing error in range

That's the code. He's copying the date into AE2 and copying below the last filled cell, but I need the TypeCopy autofill for the other one below it. I thank you now

```
Sub sub_()
    Call Atualizar_ME5A
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
    Call Atualizar_
End Sub


Sub Atualizar_ME5A()
    Range("AE2").Select

    Selection.Copy

    Range("AA2").Select

    linha = Range("AA2").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    inha2 = Range("AA2").End(xlDown).Row

    Range("AA" & linha).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Sub Atualizar_()
    linhaa = Range("AA2").End(xlDown).Row
    Range("AA" & linhaa).autoFill Destination:=Range("AA" & Cells(Rows.Count, "y").End(xlDown).Row)
End Sub
```

Comment: Please put the title in English - many just check the  title...

Comment: One note: the last cell I want to apply autofill always changes